# How to determine the source branch name in Github webhook push event?

Tags: github, webhooks, github-api, github-webhook

The push webhook only contains the *target* branch name (`ref` parameter). But I want to extract the *source* branch name, meaning the branch which was merged in the target one. I haven't found anything like that among the Github push event parameters (https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent).

But maybe I just missed it or there is another method to do so?